# how do you redirect a user who is not logged in using passport authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js

trying to stop a user from accessing my /mainpage route if they arent logged and to redirect them to login.... currently using passport and react router and components... here is my app js

```
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route exact path="/mainpage" component={MainPage} />
          <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
    );
  }
export default App;
```

this is the html-routes.js part im trying to make work

```
app.get("/mainpage", isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/signup.html"));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had an endpoint to validate their authentication status, as well as some persisted value (such as `isAuthenticated`) stored in the UI you can set up an auth gate of sorts.

```js
function AuthGate({ children ]} {
   
   return(
       <>
           {isAuthenticated && validationCheck() ? children : <Login />}
       </>
   )
}
```

and then pass render your protected routes as such

```js
function App() {
    return(
        <Router>
             <div>
                 <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                 <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                 <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                 <AuthGate>
                     <Route exact path="/mainpage" component={MainPage} />
                 </AuthGate>
                 <Footer />
        </Router>
    )
}
```

this would ensure that as long as your checks to see if a user was authenticated were true, you would render the children of the AuthGate, otherwise return the Login page. Once a user logs in, as long as there is no redirect logic, they will already be on the Mainpage route and view the content as desired. Any routes not wrapped in the AuthGate would be accessible regardless of authentication status.

Comment: @AroParada Sorry, if you wrap the return statement inside a React fragment it will work fine, I edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You can try

app.get('/mainpage', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));

Answer (score 0):

**1. declare Private Route and add auth logic**

```js
// declare Private Route
type PrivateRouteProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode
  path: string
  exact?: boolean
  rest?: never
}
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = (
  {
    children,
    path,
    exact,
    ...rest
  }: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const store = useGlobalStore()
  const loggedIn = store.loggedIn
  console.log(store.loggedIn, '??')
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      exact={exact}
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        loggedIn ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login', // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

**2. use Private Router**

```js
// use Router
const Router: React.FC = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact>
          <Redirect to={'/welcome'} />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <Route path="/login" exact>
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/403" exact>
          <Error403 />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/404" exact>
          <Error404 />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/500" exact>
          <Error500 />
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="*">
          <LayoutRoutes />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Comment: whats react.fc never used that

Comment: I use TypeScript, feel free to remove these typing annotation

Comment: if you prefer a js version, try this demo https://github.com/ryanwang520/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/Router.tsx